# React form lose his focus on update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a form with generic input, but every time I type into my input I lose the focus of this input and I have to click on them again.

```
handleChange(propertyName, event) {
    const contact = this.state.contact;
    contact[propertyName] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ contact: contact });
  }


render() {
    const FormInput = (props) => {
        return (
            <label>
                Name:
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Enter text"
                    onChange={event => this.handleChange(props.name, event)}
                    value={props.value}
                />
            </label>
        )
    }

    return (
        <form>

                <FormInput value={this.state.videoName} name="videoName" />
                <FormInput value={this.state.title} name="title" />

        </form>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't the value of the input needs to be in sync of the onchange result?

consider this:

```
handleChange(propertyName, event) {
    const contact = this.state.contact;
    contact[propertyName] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ contact: contact });
}

constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
        contact: props
    }
}

render() {
    const FormInput = (props) => {
        return (
            <label>
                Name:
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Enter text"
                    onChange={event => this.handleChange(props.name, event)}
                    value={this.state.contact.value}
                />
            </label>
        )
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <FormInput value={this.state.videoName} name="videoName" />
            <FormInput value={this.state.title} name="title" />
        </form>
    );
};
```

this code is untested but it is equivalent to getInitialState, you can either do this, or you could add a callback to your parent component in `handleChange` that updates what it sends down in the props

Comment: The handleChange function is mutating state before setState which is incorrect as it should be treat as Immutable.